# TFS project checked out unknowingly

Tags: tfs

My TFS project seems to be checked out by two users. But, they are not able to undo the changes. Even after undoing the changes the file is still checked out!! Because of this error, I'm not able to modify the folders in the project. Expecting a help.

Answer (score 1):

An administrator can undo pending changes. I think PowerTools need to be installed to get the additional context menu options. Right click on the project folder > Find > Find by Status > check Display all checked out. This will display a list of files in that folder that are checked out. Highlight all the check outs (as administrator) and undo pending changes.

Otherwise, get the developers to close their solutions and let them undo the pending changes on the project files while the solution isn't open.

Or, if the files are checked out on different machines/workspaces, then you can delete the old workspaces which will also undo all pending changes on the old workspace.